# Как динамически менять Регулярное выражение в JS?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
    $('document').ready(function() {

$('#city').on('keyup', function() {

    var inputVal = $('#city').val();
    var Reg = / /;
    Reg = /[inputVal]/; // ВОПРОС НА ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ! REGEX

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1b9f7n',
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data, textStatus) { 
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                if (inputVal.length > 1 && Reg.test(data[i])) {
                    $('#cities').append('<li class="city">' + data[i] + '</li>');
                }

            })
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("some error");
        }
    });

});

});
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction `new RegExp("шаблон", "флаги")`

Comment: То что нужно там нет.

Comment: Нужно чтобы Регулярка менялась динамически при каждом событии.

Comment: Так можно просто хранить регулярное выражение в виде строки, и каждый раз на основе строки создавать новое регулярное выражение.

Comment: @Pavel, все там есть. Формируете реулярку как строку, каждый раз разную и создаете на основании строки новый RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

### Upd. Самый очевидный вариант

Возможно, вы упустили самый очевидный вариант.

Буду исходить из того, что у вас есть алгоритм для динамического определения того, каким должно быть регулярное выражение для конкретного поля. В этом случае вы можете просто напросто переопределять на каждой итерации цикла переменную `Reg`, которая содержит в себе шаблон для проверки. Если шаблоны регулярных выражений у вас хранятся в виде строк, то преобразовать их в регулярные выражения можно вызвав конструктор `RegExp`, передав ему тот самый шаблон первым параметром и флаги (если необходимо) вторым:

```
Reg = new RegExp("шаблон", "флаги");
```

То есть в итоге может получиться что-то типа такого:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    Reg = new RegExp("шаблон", "флаги"); // *

    if (inputVal.length > 1 && Reg.test(data[i])) {
        $('#cities').append('<li class="city">' + data[i] + '</li>');
    }

})
```

Единственное, что ложится на ваши плечи - это то, как "новый" шаблон вы будете получать.

### Теория

Методом научного тыка было выяснено, что, даже несмотря на то, что шаблон регулярного выражения хранится в свойстве `pattern` объекта RegExp, которое можно изменить простым переопределением, то даже после переопределения само регулярное выражение работать по-другому не станет.

О чем речь?

Например, есть регулярное выражение, задающееся так:

```
var reg = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
```

При этом, сам шаблон в виде строки хранится в его свойстве `pattern`:

```
console.log(reg.pattern) // => "(\w+)\s(\w+)"
```

Если его переопределить:

```
reg.pattern = "(\w+)";
```

То свойство `pattern` действительно переопределяется:

```
console.log(reg.pattern) // => "(\w+)"
```

Однако на работу самого регулярного выражения это не влияет, так как его литерал остается неизменным. Следовательно,

```
reg.test("John") // => false
```

но

```
reg.test("John Smith") // => true
```

по-прежнему.

Из чего я сделал вывод, что динамически переопределить шаблон возможным не представляется.

**Кстати**, мои слова подтверждаются спецификацией. Оригинальный шаблон хранится во внутреннем свойстве `[[OriginalSource]]`, а свойство экземпляра `source` неизменно и незаписываемо.

### Иные пути решения

Насколько я понял, у вас есть набор полей, для каждого из которого где-то хранится определенное регулярное выражение (возможно, просто в виде строки). Если это так, то в таком случае вы можете динамически заранее подготовить массив с регулярными выражениями для каждого из полей, после чего проверять каждое отдельное поле специальным для этого поля регулярным выражением.

С другой стороны мне не совсем понятно, откуда берется "динамика" для подстановки регулярки. Прошу уточнить этот момент.

То есть я понимаю, что для каждого из полей вы хотите иметь свою проверку, но по какому алгоритму она подбирается?

Comment: А что мешает регулярное выражение просто хранить как строку, и создавать каждый раз на основе этой строки новое регулярное выражение.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а это уже вопрос к автору. Мне лично - ничего. Но если вопрос автором уже задан, то я предполагаю, что этот самый очевидный вариант он уже рассмотрел.

Comment: И зря. Как раз часто очевидные ответы по каким-либо причинам не видны.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин обновил на всякий случай. Но сомневаюсь, что все тут так просто.

Comment: На самом деле все оказалось очень просто, запутали два варианта объявления регулярных выражений. Один вариант это new RegExp  а еще вариант var reg = / /; так вот я пытался вставить значение из переменой во второй вариант....и никак не получалось... Потом просто сделал так var reg = new RegExp(value); и все получилось. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Pavel если ответ на свой вопрос вы нашли именно в моем ответе, то не стесняйтесь отметить его решением ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var inputVal = $('#city').val();
    var Reg = new RegExp(inputVal);
```

ВОТ ЧТО Я ИСКАЛ. Изначально пытался инициализировать через **/ /** (RegEx object) а потом как то туда вставлять... Все намного проще с помощью **new RegExp(value)**